# Can second order non-linear ODEs have non-differentiable solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lipschitz-functions

I have been recently exposed to the idea that there can exist solutions to systems with no analytical (symbolic) solutions. However, I could not find any source to the question of whether a second-order non-linear ODE of the form:
$$\ddot{x}(t) + \alpha \dot{x}(t) + g(x(t)) = 0$$
can have a non-differentiable solution, where g(x) is a non-linear function which is everywhere continuous and differentiable as well as integrable and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_ {>0} $.

Also are there any methods to prove that all solutions must be everywhere differentiable within the domain $t>0$ ?

Comment: What do you know about the Picard-Lindelöf existence-and-uniqueness theorem and its application to higher-order DE? What is your definition of solutions of DE or ODE?

Comment: I do not Lutz, I have heard about it in context of first order methods. Could you kindly provide me a source as to where I may learn this?

Comment: This is usually handled directly in context, the construction of a first-order system using the derivatives array as state vector, or some more adapted coordinates.

Comment: I believe you mean to say a state space system has unique solutions for given boundary values, right? But could you explain how that answers my question if I can define a Lyapunov which helps me prove global asymptotic stability? I am basically having a hard time convincing myself about that. Since the solutions are at least Lipschitz continous, but I am not able to define a Lebesgue measure zero directly, I am not sure about this.

Comment: A solution to your given equation is always twice continuously differentiable, more exactly  twice more differentiable than the function $g$. In the case of a boundary value problem it can happen that there are no solutions at all, but never will you get a kink in such a solution.

Comment: Exactly my thought, is there any formal way of putting this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131073/discussion-between-subhransu-sekhar-bhattacharya-and-lutz-lehmann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a solution to this equation is a function whose second derivative satisfies the equation. Therefore, the solution has to be twice differentiable. There are extended concepts of solutions which can fail to be differentiable, when the right-hand side contains objects such as impulses.

I don't see how this could happen in your equation, as g is continuous. A solution may fail to exist if g doesn't respect Lipschitz conditions (roughly, if the derivative of g is too large with respect to g), but if a solution exists, it is continuous.

Comment: Very well put, thank you for such a clear answer.